# can we set vf page to customobject as relatedlist only in custom portal is that possible to do

Tags: apex, visualforce

can we set vf page to customobject as relatedlist only in custom portal is that possible to do   because i have a scenario if the check box is checked are not records should display in organisation but if check bos is not checked then it should not display in customer portal.

Comment: It won't appear like a 'true' related list in that it will always be the first related list, coz you will have to drop it in at the end of the page. You can't set display order like with regular related lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create an inline Vf .To create an inline page:

1. From the pagelayout create a blank section
2. Create a visualforce page with standard contoller of the custom object on which we want inline(If needed additional functionalities create an extension too)
3. Pull the vf page from the pagelayout on the blank section and adjust the width and height to fit .

[here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dr7zhojDxjM&noredirect=1) on how to approach that

Here is [link from Jeff blog](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/05/08/inline-visualforce-pages-with-standard-page-layouts/) that also explains the same

Comment: Hi Mohith, i know the condition to display the records if it is checked what i want to know is can we set visualforce page to custom object as relatedlist only in customer portal

Comment: Rakesh edited and let me know if still you want more info.

Comment: yeah i am looking for more information

Comment: @rakesh:Please find the updated answer

Comment: sorry Mohith I think You didn't understood my question i know hoe to add a vf page object and how to handle the class for that what i want to know is i need to set a Vf page as related list to object only in customer portal it should not  in my salesforce login

Comment: related list to show in customer portal but not in salesforce login so is it possible

Comment: well related list in portal also comes from the pagelayout if you are aware .Thanks again .May be you may like to get that pagelayout and modify

Comment: so i need to create new page layout for object where i can add my visualforce page and give the permission with this layout to customer portal is that correct

Comment: You will need to find the pagelayout that you have on portal .It may be default pagelayout.Go to the portal profile and under custom object see the pagelayout assigned for the record type.Hope this helps.Good luck

Comment: If it helps please upvote and accept the answer so that it helps for other people finding the answer.